# Terminal in Ubuntu doesn't work using Ctrl + Alt + T

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

When using Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work for launching the Terminal. I tried changing its shortcut key but still it won't work but when I'm using *Xubuntu*, the said shortcut key works. How can I fix it? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I originally installed Xubuntu 20.04 with a GNOME Version 3.36.2 then installed Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Have you checked the `Keyboard Shortcuts` section in settings. Search for `Launch Terminal`. Then check the shortcut. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: I already did, and i changed it to "Super + T", but still to no avail, neither of them works.

Comment: If you changed it to `Super + T` then the previous shortcut won't work. If the want `Ctrl + Alt + T` then reset it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it somehow, by going to Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > + (by scrolling down to the bottom) and entering this, Name: Terminal, Command: `xfce4-terminal`, Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Nevertheless, thank you for helping.

Comment: The default terminal in Ubuntu Desktop is GNOME terminal. It seems it wasn't installed when you installed ubuntu-desktop package.